# windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0

Tags: python

I've created a simple program that clicks black tiles in a piano.

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random   
import win32api, win32com
import image


#RGB (1,1,1)
#TILE 1 X = 353 Y = 380
#TILE 2 X = 404 Y = 380
#TILE 3 X = 455 Y = 380
#TILE 4 X = 511 Y = 380


def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

while keyboard.is_pressed("q") == False:

    if pyautogui.pixel(353, 380) [0] == 1:
        click(353,380)
    if pyautogui.pixel(404, 380) [0] == 1:
        click(404,380)
    if pyautogui.pixel(455, 380) [0] == 1:
        click(455,380)
    if pyautogui.pixel(511, 380) [0] == 1:
        click(511,380)


raise WindowsError("windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0")
OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0
```

It gives this error, does anyone know why? I tried to search for it but nothing showed up.

EDIT (this is the error):

```
Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 122, in __win32_openDC
    raise WindowsError("windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0")
OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0
```

Comment: Are you raising the `WindowsError` intentionally? Or is that a part of the traceback?

Comment: It's part of the traceback

Comment: Could you include the full traceback so that we can see what line in your code causes this error? :)

Comment: Yes, there it is!

Comment: There should be more to the traceback; it should show which line of **your** code causes the error :). What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 3.8

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59595934/12326283) answer suggests trying to run on Python 3.7, instead of 3.8. For example, in terminal (if Python3.8 is installed): `python3.7 your file.py`

Comment: I created [an issue](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/579) for this on github as there are easily 5-10 posts on this issue on SO as well as numerous others on reddit. So many that it's hard to find details on `windll.user32.ReleaseDC` itself because all the hits are for pyautogui issues! I'd follow along with the github issue. In my opinion, all the "just downgrade" suggestions are not answers, nor solutions. That said, this isn't a howto question either (fitting for SO), it's a bug and needs to be addressed upstream, not here.

Comment: @gmdev here's [the source](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/0446e87235e0079f591f0c49ece7d487dedc2f9a/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L112).

Comment: There is a pending [PR](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/pull/73) to `pyscreeze` that addresses this now. Probably a while until this gets release, but one could use my fork directly in the meantime.