# PyScreeze Crashing: OSError: windll.gdi32.GetPixel failed : return -1

Tags: python, pyautogui, pyscreeze

Trying to check the colour of a pixel:

```
while True:
    x, y = 1742, 979
    r,g,b = pyautogui.pixel(x, y)
    if b == 106:
        #some more code
```

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 119, in __win32_openDC
    yield hDC
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 610, in pixel
    raise WindowsError("windll.gdi32.GetPixel failed : return {}".format(color))
OSError: windll.gdi32.GetPixel failed : return -1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\OneDrive\Combined_180222_desktop_version .py", line 500, in <module>
    detection()
  File "c:\Users\OneDrive\Combined_180222_desktop_version .py", line 468, in detection
    r,g,b = py.pixel(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 614, in pixel
    return (r, g, b)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 123, in __win32_openDC
    raise WindowsError("windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0")
OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0
```

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146513/pyautogui-and-pyscreeze-crash-with-windll-user32-releasedc-failed) says: " This is an issue that has been fixed in PyScreeze 0.1.28, so you just need to update it by running `pip install -U pyscreeze`."

I'm on PyScreeze 0.1.28 so that's not it. The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586046/fastest-way-to-take-a-screenshot-with-python-on-windows) talks about manually releasing all the DCs but I'm not sure how to do that when I'm using the `.pixel` function and not win32 directly.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround until someone who manages the package replies. Not fixing the error, just handling it with `try` and `except`.

```
   while True:
        try:
            x, y = 1742, 979
            r,g,b = pyautogui.pixel(x, y)
            if b == 106:
                #some more code
        except:
            x, y = 1742, 979
            r,g,b = pyautogui.pixel(x, y)
            if b == 106:
                #some more code
```